# How to design an interface for two similar but distinct objects

Tags: java, api-design, javafx

I'm designing an API for a JavaFX control to be submitted to the ControlsFX library. This control is called the `ViewManager`, and its purpose is to hold a collection of `View` instances, all of which feed off of the same set of data (items to display, selection state, view settings, etc...)

My original attempt was to have `View` be an abstract class that defines all of the things it needs -- things such as selection and focus models, a collection of items to visualize, and a few other things (some of which I haven't conceptualized yet).

Views are able to exist in isolation from a `ViewManager`, but I want to design the `ViewManager` to have many of the same functions of a `View` so that all views in the manager can feed off the manager's data and stay in sync with eachother. The problem I'm running into, however, is that a proper implementation of `View` (such as `GridView` or `ListView`) has additional features that makes no sense to a `ViewManager` (such as a reference to its `ViewManager` and its cell factory). For this reason, it feels improper to make `ViewManager` extend `View`.

One other thought I had was to abstract `View` away into an interface, and then change my class to `AbstractView`. This may have alleviated the issue above, but then I discovered that I needed this interface to define signatures for things that are implementation specific -- things such as `itemsProperty()` used by my selection model class to attach a listener.

The only solution I can come up with is to have `ViewManager` override the functions that it does not use, and have these throw something like `UnsupportedOperationException`. There's also the fact that a `ViewManager` should not contain another `ViewManager`, so I would also have to check for that special case when adding a view to the manager, and respond accordingly.

What seemed to me like a fairly straightforward idea is now turning into a mess of bad design. Is there a better way I can get around this?

For reference, here are my implementations I have so far:

### View

```
/**
 * Abstract base class for all Views that will be usable by the {@link ViewManager}
 *
 * @param <T> The base type of the object that this view will display information about
 * @param <C> The base type of the {@link IndexedCell} that this view uses to display individual records
 */
public abstract class View<T, C extends AbstractViewCell<T>> extends ControlsFXControl {

    /***************************************************************************
     *
     * Properties
     *
     **************************************************************************/

    // --- Cell Factory
    private ObjectProperty<Callback<View<T, C>, C>> cellFactory = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "cellFactory"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    public ObjectProperty<Callback<View<T, C>, C>> cellFactoryProperty() { return cellFactory; }
    public Callback<View<T, C>, C> getCellFactory() { return cellFactory.get(); }
    public void setCellFactory(Callback<View<T, C>, C> cellFactory) { this.cellFactory.set(cellFactory); }

    // --- Checkbox
    private final BooleanProperty showCheckbox = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "showCheckbox", Boolean.FALSE); //$NON-NLS-1$
    public BooleanProperty showCheckboxProperty() { return showCheckbox; }
    public boolean getShowCheckbox() { return showCheckbox.get(); }
    public void setShowCheckbox(boolean showCheckbox) { this.showCheckbox.set(showCheckbox); }

    // --- Items
    private ListProperty<T> items = new SimpleListProperty<>(this, "items", FXCollections.observableArrayList()); //$NON-NLS-1$
    public ListProperty<T> itemsProperty() { return items; }
    public ObservableList<T> getItems() { return items.get(); }
    public void setItems(ObservableList<T> items) { this.items.set(items); }

    // --- Focus Model
    private ObjectProperty<FocusModel<T>> focusModel = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "focusModel"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    public ObjectProperty<FocusModel<T>> focusModelProperty() { return focusModel; }
    public FocusModel<T> getFocusModel() { return focusModel.get(); }
    public void setFocusModel(FocusModel<T> focusModel) { this.focusModel.set(focusModel); }

    // --- Selection Model
    private ObjectProperty<MultipleSelectionModel<T>> selectionModel = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "selectionModel"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    public ObjectProperty<MultipleSelectionModel<T>> selectionModelProperty() { return selectionModel; }
    public MultipleSelectionModel<T> getSelectionModel() { return selectionModel.get(); }
    public void setSelectionModel(MultipleSelectionModel<T> selectionModel) { this.selectionModel.set(selectionModel); }

    // --- View Manager
    private ObjectProperty<ViewManager<T>> viewManager = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "viewManager");
    public ObjectProperty<ViewManager<T>> viewManagerProperty() { return viewManager; }
    public ViewManager<T> getViewManager() { return viewManager.get(); }
    public void setViewManager(ViewManager<T> viewManager) { this.viewManager.set(viewManager); }



    /***************************************************************************
     *
     * Listeners
     *
     **************************************************************************/

    /**
     * Here we make sure that if, for whatever reason, the ViewManager changes, we un-bind and re-bind
     * the appropriate properties.
     */
    ChangeListener<ViewManager<T>> VIEW_MANAGER_PROPERTY_LISTENER = (o, oldManager, currentManager) -> {
        if (oldManager != null) {
            focusModel.unbindBidirectional(oldManager.focusModelProperty());
            selectionModel.unbindBidirectional(oldManager.selectionModelProperty());
            items.unbindBidirectional(oldManager.itemsProperty());
            showCheckbox.unbindBidirectional(oldManager.showCheckboxProperty());
        }

        if (currentManager != null) {
            focusModel.bindBidirectional(currentManager.focusModelProperty());
            selectionModel.bindBidirectional(currentManager.selectionModelProperty());
            items.bindBidirectional(currentManager.itemsProperty());
            showCheckbox.bindBidirectional(currentManager.showCheckboxProperty());
        }
    };

    WeakChangeListener<ViewManager<T>> WEAK_VIEW_MANAGER_PROPERTY_LISTENER = new WeakChangeListener<>(VIEW_MANAGER_PROPERTY_LISTENER);



    /***************************************************************************
     *
     * Constructors
     *
     **************************************************************************/

    public View() {
        viewManager.addListener(WEAK_VIEW_MANAGER_PROPERTY_LISTENER);
    }
}
```

### ViewManager

```
public class ViewManager<T> extends ControlsFXControl {

    /***************************************************************************
     *
     * Listeners
     *
     **************************************************************************/



    /***************************************************************************
     *
     * Properties
     *
     **************************************************************************/

    // --- Checkbox
    private final BooleanProperty showCheckbox = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "showCheckbox", Boolean.FALSE); //$NON-NLS-1$
    public BooleanProperty showCheckboxProperty() { return showCheckbox; }
    public boolean getShowCheckbox() { return showCheckbox.get(); }
    public void setShowCheckbox(boolean showCheckbox) { this.showCheckbox.set(showCheckbox); }

    // --- Items
    private final ListProperty<T> items = new SimpleListProperty<>(this, "items", FXCollections.observableArrayList()); //$NON-NLS-1$
    public ListProperty<T> itemsProperty() { return items; }
    public ObservableList<T> getItems() { return items.get(); }

    // --- Focus Model
    private ObjectProperty<FocusModel<T>> focusModel = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "focusModel"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    public ObjectProperty<FocusModel<T>> focusModelProperty() { return focusModel; }
    public FocusModel<T> getFocusModel() { return focusModel.get(); }
    public void setFocusModel(FocusModel<T> focusModel) { this.focusModel.set(focusModel); }


    // --- Selection Model
    private ObjectProperty<MultipleSelectionModel<T>> selectionModel = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "selectionModel"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    public ObjectProperty<MultipleSelectionModel<T>> selectionModelProperty() { return selectionModel; }
    public MultipleSelectionModel<T> getSelectionModel() { return selectionModel.get(); }
    public void setSelectionModel(MultipleSelectionModel<T> selectionModel) { this.selectionModel.set(selectionModel); }

    // -- Views
    private final ListProperty<View<T, ? extends IndexedCell<T>>> views
            = new SimpleListProperty<View<T, ? extends IndexedCell<T>>>(FXCollections.observableArrayList()) {

        @Override
        protected void invalidated() {
            get().forEach(view -> view.setViewManager(ViewManager.this));
        }

        @Override
        public Object getBean() {
            return ViewManager.this;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "views";
        }
    };
    public ListProperty<View<T, ? extends IndexedCell<T>>> viewsProperty() { return views; }
    public ObservableList<View<T, ? extends IndexedCell<T>>> getViews() { return views.get(); }
    public void setViews(ObservableList<View<T, ? extends IndexedCell<T>>> views) { this.views.set(views); }



    /***************************************************************************
     *
     * Private Implementation
     *
     **************************************************************************/

    private void updateAllSelectionModels(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Integer> change) {
        while (change.next()) {
            if (change.wasAdded()) {
                for (Integer added : change.getAddedSubList()) {
                    views.forEach(view -> view.getSelectionModel().select(added));
                }
            }

            if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                for (Integer removed : change.getRemoved()) {
                    views.forEach(view -> view.getSelectionModel().clearSelection(removed));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are many more pieces involved, but they're not relevant to the problem discussed here.